# Can't assign a class to an infoBox in Google Maps v3

Tags: class, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

Is anyone else having problems with [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)?

Is there a better way to create infoBoxes and assign them classes? I can't set a class!

```
var myOptions = {
  content: boxText,
  disableAutoPan: false,
  boxClass: "CLASS", <----
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
  zIndex: null,
  boxStyle: {
    background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
    opacity: 0.75,
    width: "280px"
  },
  closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
  closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
  infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
  isHidden: false,
  pane: "floatPane",
  enableEventPropagation: false
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/456hH/)

Element Attributes:

[image]

Comment: thanks! you gave me hope, but I still can't set the background color! http://jsfiddle.net/456hH/12/